# Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component inside export

Tags: reactjs, native

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
export default memo(function Banner() {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar bg="light" variant="light" expand="lg" sticky="top">
        <LinkContainer to="/">
          <Navbar.Brand bg="dark">
            <img src={logo} className="logo-svg" alt="Logo" />
            {config.title}
          </Navbar.Brand>
        </LinkContainer>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse className="ml-5" id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="mr-auto" activeKey={location.pathname}>
            <LinkContainer to="/grid">
              <Nav.Link eventKey="/grid">Grid</Nav.Link>
            </LinkContainer>
            <LinkContainer to="/form">
              <Nav.Link eventKey="/form">Form</Nav.Link>
            </LinkContainer>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    </>
  );
    })
```

Hello.
I'm trying to apply my react code to react native but getting the error.
what i'm missing here if i'm trying to export the written function
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to define the function first and then `export default memo(Banner)` on the bottom of the page?

Comment: @user3193813 this code looks fine, other than i don't see what `config` refers to. Are you sure this is the component that the error originated from?

Comment: export default memo(function Banner() {
  const location = useLocation();
  return <>Hello</>;
}); getting same error